# DIfferent values for android:layout_weight="" for different versions

Tags: android, android-widget, android-resources

I created a widget. But it is not compatible in different versions (In the layout only). 
So i have to give values for android:layout_weight="" according to the version (For ICS it is 1.27 and others it is 1.17). How i can do it ?

Answer (score 4):

Do some versioning, put different values in different folders like so...

```
res > values-v3 > strings.xml
    > values-14 > strings.xml
```

also you can have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html